# Castle ActiveRecord, C# - Improving performance of ActiveRecordMediator.FindAll method through reducing executed queries

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, activerecord, castle-activerecord

Currently I am maintaining a legacy C# application that uses Castle ActiveRecord to retrieve data from the database. Our client has complained about the performance of the application when a certain page is requested. The page in question shows a table with a large number of invoices. This is done through the ActiveRecordMediator.FindAll method that takes a parameter for the requested type and a parameter for an ICriterion expression. Once the gridview is filled with the array of invoices a very large number of queries is executed. I suspect that this is causing the bad performance. Ideally I would like to limit the number of queries that are executed. Unfortunately my attempts so far have not been successful since I am unfamiliar with Castle ActiveRecord and ORMs in general.

I presume this problem is related to lazy loading and possibly the 'select N+1' problem. I have tried adjusting the FetchMode to no avail. So far Google searches on how to solve this problem related to the 'ActiveRecordMediator' have not resulted in any applicable strategies. So I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how to improve the performance of the 'ActiveRecordMediator.FindAll' method.

Below you will find a condensed version of the code that results in the numerous queries.

**Methods that are called on page load:**

```
var invoices = new List<Invoice>(
     Invoice.GetAll(Expression.Eq("BetaalSpecificatieVerstuurd", false)))

invoices.Sort(
    new Comparison<Invoice>(
        delegate (Factuur f1, Factuur f2)
        {
            return -1 * f1.ID.CompareTo(f2.ID);
        }));

// After this point all the queries are executed.
gridviewList.DataSource = invoices;
gridviewList.DataBind();
```

**GetAll method:**

```
public static T[] GetAll(ICriterion criterion)
{
    if (criterion == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("criteria");

    return Source.FindAll(typeof(T), criterion) as T[];
}
```

**FindAll method implementation:**

```
public Array FindAll(Type t, ICriterion criterion)
{
    ICriterion additionalCriterion = Expression.Eq("CompanyID", CurrentCompanyId);
    ICriterion criterionToApply = Expression.And(criterion, additionalCriterion);

    return ActiveRecordMediator.FindAll(t, criterionToApply);
}
```

**Query that gets executed multiple times:**

```
SELECT
    this_.ID as ID0_0_,
    this_.var1 as var12_0_0_,
    this_.var2 as var23_0_0_,
    this_.var3 as var34_0_0_,
    this_.var4 as var45_0_0_,
    ...
FROM
    Opmerking this_
WHERE
    ((this_.RelevantId = @p0 and this_.Type = @p1) and
    this_.CompanyID = @p2)
ORDER BY
    this_.IsImportant desc,
    this_.Processed asc,
    this_.Date desc
```

**EDIT:**

After some help from @mjwills I was able to isolate the problem. In the .ascx webpage different properties of the class Invoice were displayed in a gridview. Most of them were already loaded because they were contained in the database table invoices. However a field 'remarks' was not. This resulted in a call to the database every time the 'remarks' field was retrieved. My first hunch is to eagerly load the remarks data as well. I am unsure how this can be achieved. Will update when I know more.

Comment: Are there any queries using `RelevantId`?

Comment: I do not know. I am unsure what the `this_.RelevantId` does in the query that is generated. From what I can tell (but unfortunately the business logic is quite opague) retrieving this data does not need the `RelevantId`. However it is a generic function, so it might be that this field is used in other cases.

Comment: I did not, but I have just now. RelevantId is used in multiple classes and it seems to generally stand for the Id of the object that is retrieved (in lieu of a property with the name of 'Id'). In this case the RelevantId would likely be the Id of the Invoice itself. Is there something in particular I should be looking for? Or is there some specific information I could provide that would help you assess the problem better?

Comment: Very interesting the `FindAll` method is only hit 5 times (and how stupid of me to not check this before). I just updated the answer to include more of the code. Apparently the queries are only executed when the gridview is filled. Which leads me to believe that it has to do with lazy loading.